# error while lauching eclipse php in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: eclipse

I had been installed and removed my eclipse mars from my Ubuntu . Now I am not able to launch my eclipse oxygen for PHP developers.

I am getting below error once I click on eclipse.exe file

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/asif/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/asif/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.2.v20161124-1400/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/asif/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/asif/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.401.v20161122-1740/eclipse_1618.so
-startup /home/asif/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 36801c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/asif/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
```

Comment: That exit code `13` could mean you are trying to run Eclipse 32bit on a 64bit JVM. Is that the case?

Comment: please look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635506/error-starting-eclipse-in-linux-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13), and [this](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-fix-a-quotjvm-terminated-exit-code13quot-error-in-eclipse)